# Можно ли как-то удалить второстепенный поток и с этого же места запустить основной?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

У меня в методе заполняется массив, каждое число по нажатию кнопки, это выполняет второстепенный. Могу ли я как-то после заполнения массива еще в этом же методе, завершить этот поток и чтобы основной тут же продолжил. Подскажите. Например, чтобы метод DijkstraAlgo выполнялся уже в основном. Вот пример кода:

```
 private void Array()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                Clicked = false;
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Vertexes.Content = $"Введите расстояние от {i+1}-го пункта до {j+1}-го пункта =");                 
                while(Clicked == false)
                {

                }
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => text = Convert.ToInt32(Weight.Text));
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Weight.Text = " ");
                graph[i, j] = text;

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(graph.ToString());
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Result.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
        DijkstraAlgo(graph, 0, n);
    }
```

Comment: Что-то вы намудрили. Может всё-таки лучше стандартно на элементы интерфейса какие-то обработчики повесить, например, на поля ввода или на кнопки какие-то, там проверять, что введено всё, что нужно, и запускать что нужно.

Comment: А не знаю, у меня интерфейс уже готовый и менять нельзя, а там только одна кнопка. Приходится выкручиваться. Чтобы можно было по одному элементу в текст бокс вводить, и как все введены, запускается алгоритм.

Comment: Ну не знаю, только так же через `Invoke` видимо можно в главный поток попасть. Вообще выглядит как-то совсем криво это всё. Я бы лучше зарефакторил, чем такой велосипед дальше катить.

Comment: Уберите вызов `DijkstraAlgo` из этого метода. Элементарно же! И вызывайте его отдельно.